# Push cloud code to heroku from parse.com not working

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, migration, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

There is a default function in 'cloud/main.js' of parse-server-example which is working fine I can see 'Hi' response in my iOS app simulator.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) 
{
     res.success('Hi');
});
```

After I added my own function into this file as followes:

```
Parse.Cloud.define(testFunction', function(req, res)
{
     res.success('Test function');
});
```

and run the following commands:

```
$ git add index.js
$ git commit -m "Changed configuration values"
$ git push heroku master
```

and call it in my app function it shows an error:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"testFunction"
                       withParameters:nil
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@",object);

         }
         NSLog(@"%@",error.debugDescription);
     }
     ];
```

[Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.13.0)

But the 'hello' function is working fine. How would that work?

Comment: Ok This issue has been resolved as I was committing wrong file to commit the cloud/main.js i did:                                                                    $ git add ./cloud/main.js
$ git commit -m "Changed configuration values"
$ git push heroku master

Comment: But now I have another issue the cloud running code responding {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.13.0)

Answer (score 1):

```
Parse.Cloud.define(testFunction', function(req, res)
```

You're missing a quote in front of `testFunction'`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am able to resolve this issue as I was not committing the 'cloud/main.js' file to heroku server. But now I have another issue. My mandrill code is not working any more. with heroku. Here I have put the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207110/mandrill-with-parse-server-not-working-on-heroku-migration/36232196#36232196