# Mandrill with parse server not working on heroku migration

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, mandrill, parse-server

I have migrate app from parse.com to heroku with mLab and everything works fine except cloud code.

I am using Mandrill for sending email from parse cloud code which is not working with heroku

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Installed mandrill ~0.1.0 into parse-server-example and push the code to heroku app
2. Put the cloud code into '/cloud/main.js'
3. Called the function from iOS app which respond error as:
   [Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.13.0).

Here is my code script:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendMail", function(request, response) {
                   var Mandrill = require('mandrill');
                   Mandrill.initialize('xxxxxx-xxxxx');

                   Mandrill.sendEmail({
                                      message: {
                                      text: "ffff",
                                      subject: "hello",
                                      from_email: "xxxxx@gmail.com",
                                      from_name: "pqr",
                                      to: [
                                           {
                                           email: "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
                                           name: "trump"
                                           }
                                           ]
                                      },
                                      async: true
                                      },{
                                      success: function(httpResponse) {
                                      console.log(httpResponse);
                                      response.success("Email sent!");
                                      },
                                      error: function(httpResponse) {
                                      console.error(httpResponse);
                                      response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
                                      }
                                      });
                   });
```

But after calling 'sendMail' function I am getting this error:

[Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.13.0).
================================== MailGun ==========================

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {

    var api_key = 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var domain = 'smtp.mailgun.org';
    var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

    var data = {
                 from: 'xxxxxxxald@gmail.com',
                 to: 'xxxxx8@gmail.com',
                 subject: 'Hello',
                 text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
               };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
                                           console.log(body);
                                           });
        //res.success(req.params.name);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with sendgrid, but I finally find a way around the problem.

I think this steps may help you,

1. Miss some brackets or some code separator? ( try rewritting the entire code in the main.js )
2. The app is actually running? ( when you type "heroku open" in the terminal you get the default message? ) - if not check step 1.
3. If the previous are not working, rollback to a safe build and Add the add-ons in the heroku dashboard instead of installing them yourself, then download the git and do any changes to git and then push.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both of your first two steps are fine. My app is running. But Mandrill code is not. There is no mandrill add-on available. And what do mean by download git and push which git (parse server)? Or if you have any way to execute my mandrill code.

Comment: well since there is no mandrill add-on it wont work, the reason I suggested this step is because when you add a component through the dashboard, if I am not wrong, heroku will do some changes to the git in order to implement the add-on, this way you dont have to do them yourself and maybe skip some part of the process. So, after doing this you download the git using the heroku toolbelt and then do the other changes to the git and then push it to the heroku app, that is how I manage to get sendgrid working.

Comment: oh by the way did you enabled cloud code?? you need to go the dockerfile in the git and uncomment this : VOLUME /parse/cloud

Comment: I uncomment the line in Dockfile and push it to heroku git but same error.                                           [Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.13.0)

Comment: Well the error message is now different, I think the internal server error means that something is wrong with the code. try putting the initializer of mandrill outside the cloud function

Comment: I am now trying to use MailGun the code is just update above please check . This code gives me JSON error like this:- Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Comment: I really dont know much about this other services since I use sendgrid, but try putting the api key, domain and mailgun intiializer outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have pasted from cloud code main.js code that is working using Mandrill on heroku parse application to send password recovery e-mail.

in cloud code main.js:

```
var mandrill_key = process.env.MANDRILL_KEY;

var Mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');

var mandrill_client = new Mandrill.Mandrill(mandrill_key);

{
    success: function(gameScore) {
        //alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);

        mandrill_client.messages.send(
        {
            message: {
                html: "<p>Hello " + firstUser.get('fullname') + ",</p><p>We received your request to reset your password.</p><p>Your user name is <strong>" + firstUser.get('username') + "</strong>. Please <a href=\"http://test-sample-app.herokuapp.com/?#/account/reset/password/" + jsonct.ct + "\">click here</a> to create a new password. This link will expire in one hour after this mail was sent</p><p>If you need additional help, just let us know.</p><p>SampleCompany Support<br>customerservice@example.com</p><p>Copyright Sample Company, Inc. 2014-2017</p>",
                subject: "Sample Company Name account recovery",
                from_email: "customerservice@example.com",
                from_name: "Sample Company Name",
                to: [
                    {
                        email: firstUser.get('email'),
                        name: firstUser.get('fullname')
                    }
                ]
            },
            async: true
        },
        //Success
        function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse);
            //alert("Email sent!");
        },
        //Failure
        function(httpResponse) {
            console.error(httpResponse);
            //alert("Uh oh, something went wrong");
        });
    },
    error: function(gameScore, error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        //alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    },
    useMasterKey: true
})
```